# conditionally merge cells' contents in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking for a pandanic way to turn the following df:

```
    name    desc
0   A       a
1   NaN     aa
2   NaN     aaa
3   B       b
4   NaN     bb
```

into:

```
    name    desc
0   A       a
            aa
            aaa
3   B       b
            bb

# strings in desc are concat-ed together with end of line char
```

I am thinking of the general directions of either itertuple or backfill+groupby, but both of those approaches require some juggling.

here is the starting point:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ['A', nan, nan, 'B', nan],
    'desc': ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb']}
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a combination of `fillna(method='ffill')` and `groupby`.

How does this look?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ['A', nan, nan, 'B', nan],
    'desc': ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb']}
)

df['name'] = df['name'].fillna(method='ffill')

df = df.groupby('name')['desc'].apply(lambda d: '\n'.join(d)).reset_index()
print df
```

prints

```
  name        desc
0    A  a\naa\naaa
1    B       b\nbb
```

Comment: Thank you, the key sentence is what I am looking for. I had to do a `for` loop on the return of the `groupby()`

Answer (score 3):

you can call `ffill` directly and `agg` without using `apply` and `lambda`

```
In [719]: df.ffill().groupby('name').agg('\n'.join).reset_index()
Out[719]:
  name        desc
0    A  a\naa\naaa
1    B       b\nbb
```

or:

```
In [729]: df.ffill().groupby('name', as_index=False).agg({'desc': '\n'.join})
Out[729]:
  name        desc
0    A  a\naa\naaa
1    B       b\nbb
```

Comment: I had to really sit down and fully understand what `df.groupby()` really does, and learn about `agg()` and `transform()` in order to fully appreciate your answer. I see that `reset_index()` and `as_index=false` too, RTFM!

Comment: this is great, I didn't realize you could use `agg` this way.